# What programming language(s) should I use to make a web-based argument mapping app?

Tags: javascript, html, diagram

I want to make a web-based argument mapping app that so my students can produce maps similar to that shown in the attached image. Boxes connect to each other as in a folder tree. Box size and box orientation adjust automatically as users enter text. The map grows on a n infinite 'canvas'. Boxes and nodes can be dragged and dropped to other positions on the map. Users need to be able to set border colors. Maps can be exported as PDFs, etc, etc.

I'm guessing this is all doable with Javascript, but does anyone know about any libraries that can help? Or should I investigate other languages?

[image]

Comment: Some people consider this kind of question opinion based, so answers are likely to be voted down or deleted. There are lots of libraries to draw diagrams in js, I'm sure it'd be possible to create something like the example you've given. This article gives a good overview on some of the options available to you https://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams/

Comment: Fantastic. That should get me started. Thanks.